# Which one is better to user API View or Function based view or Generic Viewset

Tags: django

I am confused which one to use in which scenario in Django view

official documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Django-Restframework` i would prefer `ModelViewset` for built-in `list,retrive,get,post,delete` method. But if the options are API View or Function based view or Generic Viewset, i will choose `Generic Viewset` as this gives shortcuts that map closely to database models. Adds commonly required behavior for standard list and detail views. Gives some attributes like, the serializer_class, also gives pagination_class, filter_backend, etc which are very powerful.